# Symfony Event - Form muestra doble mensaje de error

Tags: formularios, symfony2, symfony, twig

tengo un formulario (no asociado a una entidad) de busqueda con varios campos:

- apellido
- nombre
- dni
- cuil

***El formulario valida pero muestra un doble mensaje de error***

como se ve a continuacion:

*

```
Verificar los campos erroneos
Revise los siguientes errores:
```

Luego de ese error tambien muestra:

```
Debe ingresar un Nº de documento
```

Que es un error que le inserto con un eventLIstener de symfony.
*

A nivel de twig esta definido de esta forma:

```
   {{ form_start(form, {'custom_options': {'avoid_required_message': true}})}}
                <p></p>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    {{ form_row(form.busqueda) }}<p></p>
                    <div id="condicion">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div id="ape">
                                    {{ form_row(form.campoApellido) }}<p></p>
                                    {{ form_row(form.campoNombre) }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div id="doc">
                                    {{ form_row(form.campoDni) }}<p></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div id="cuil">
                                    {{ form_row(form.campoCuil) }}<p></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="enviar">    
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar" /><p></p>
                    </div> 
                    {{ form_rest(form)}}
                    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

El eventlistener en el archivo type esta definido como

```
 public function validarDatosIngresados(FormEvent $event) {
    $datos = $event->getData();
    $opcion = $datos['busqueda'];
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if($opcion == 'documento' && strlen($datos['campoDni']) == 0) {
        $error = new FormError("Debe ingresar un Nº de documento");
        $form->addError($error);
    }

    if($opcion == 'cuil' && strlen($datos['campoCuil']) == 0) {
        $error = new FormError("Debe ingresar un Nº de C.U.I.L.");
        $form->addError($error);
    }

    if($opcion == 'apellido' && strlen($datos['campoApellido']) == 0 && strlen($datos['campoNombre']) == 0) {
        $error = new FormError("Debe ingresar un apellido y/o nombre del aportante");
        $form->addError($error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolvi aplicando ideas de POO, incorporando atributos de clase como se ve:

```
private $opcion;
private $apellido;
private $nombre;
private $dni;
private $cuil;
```

Declaro un *event* sobre todo el formulario como:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'guardarDatosIngresados'));
```

Declaro *event* sobre los diversos inputs de mi formulario

```
$builder->get('campoCuil')->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'validarCuil'));
```

Luego por ejemplo declaro mi funcion *validarCuil* y *guardarDatosIngresados* de la siguiente manera:

```
 public function guardarDatosIngresados(FormEvent $event) {
    // leo los datos ingresados por el usuario
    $datos = $event->getData();
    // datos es un array asociativo, debo acceder a cada parte que me interesa
    $this->opcion = $datos['busqueda'];
    $this->apellido = $datos['campoApellido'];
    $this->nombre = $datos['campoNombre'];
    $this->cuil = $datos['campoCuil'];
    $this->dni = $datos['campoDni'];
}

public function validarCuil(FormEvent $event) {
    // accedo al formulario
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if($this->opcion == 'cuil' && strlen($this->cuil) == 0) {
        // creo un mensaje de error
        $error = new FormError("Debe ingresar un Nº de C.U.I.L.");
        // indico al formulario que debe agregar un mensaje de error 
        // SOBRE el campo que esta siendo escuchado
        $form->addError($error);
    }
}
```